# FFmpeg Video is not shown, after encoding audio and video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to encode my video which also has audio in it

```
ffmpeg -i .\A0002780.kava23_Fin.avi -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -crf 20 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

This command is working OK with no errors. But when I play the video, I can hear only audio and can't see the video.

Here are the logs of the command:

```
ffmpeg version N-83280-gcba4f0e Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid 
--enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-     avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls 
--enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b -- 
enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm -- 
enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable- 
libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 -- 
enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy -- 
enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame -- 
enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable- 
libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable- 
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma - 
-enable-decklink --enable-zlib


libavutil      55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
  libavcodec     57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavformat    57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 71.100 /  6. 71.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
[avi @ 0000000000f973a0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from '.\A0002780.kava23_Fin.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17697237 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 7680x3840, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 2.2
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 5.4.0][64 bit] 8bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-6 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 8 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 3 / wpp(120 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 32 / 16
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : dia / 57 / 0 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 25 / 250 / 0 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 5 / 3 / 0
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 0 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 1 / off / off
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 1 / 0.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-20.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=2 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip tmvp fast-intra
x265 [info]: tools: strong-intra-smoothing lslices=8 deblock
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.65.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265) ([35][0][0][0] / 0x0023), yuv420p, 7680x3840, q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.75.100 libx265
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.75.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  750 fps=0.7 q=-0.0 Lsize=   17320kB time=00:00:30.04 bitrate=4722.1kbits/s speed=0.0269x
video:16823kB audio:469kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 0.159117%
x265 [info]: frame I:      3, Avg QP:22.35  kb/s: 250515.20
x265 [info]: frame P:    187, Avg QP:24.28  kb/s: 10607.54
x265 [info]: frame B:    560, Avg QP:27.67  kb/s: 1267.19
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 1.1% 1.1% 0.0% 97.9%

encoded 750 frames in 1117.63s (0.67 fps), 4593.04 kb/s, Avg QP:26.80
[aac @ 00000000027c91e0] Qavg: 456.871
```

It seems that there is no error and I can see that video and audio are encoded properly.

Any idea?

Comment: Please add ffmpeg log output and even input/output file examples if possible

Comment: What are you using to play the video? does `ffplay output.mp4` work?

Comment: Show the complete log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: I have the same problem with ffplay, I see audio but the screen is white

Comment: You can see my answer given below. And could you please post the command so that I can check where is the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the above question. I added `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to the command and I can see the video and hear the audio as well.

Here is the updated command:

```
ffmpeg -i .\A0002780.kava23_Fin.avi -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 20 -c:a aac output.mp4
```